# Why $\overline{\hat{f}(k)}=\hat{f}(-k)$ If $f \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

**Proposition:** Suppose $f$ real valued $2\pi$ periodic and integrable function on a closed interval of $2\pi$ length. Then $$ \overline{\hat{f}(k)}=\hat{f}(-k)$$
**Proof:**
We can easily see that:
$$ \overline{\hat{f}(k)}= \overline{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx} =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\overline{f(x)e^{-ikx}}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{ikx}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-i(-k)x}dx=\hat{f}(-k)$$
I can't see we this is true only if $f$ is real valued fuction.
I know that $f$ is real valued fuction if $f=\overline{f}$, but where in the proof we use this fact ?

Comment: Note that $\overline{f(k)e^{-ikx}}=\overline{f(x)}\cdot \overline{e^{-ikx}}=f(x)e^{ikx}$.

Comment: If $f$ is not real valued then $\overline{\widehat{f}(k)}=\widehat{\overline{f}}(-k).$